# List Schema XML

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, pnp-powershell

I have SharePoint 2013 sites and I have created the task list.

Now I want to export that Schema XML using CSOM or PnP PowerShell.

Can someone suggest me?

Comment: Do you want to export schema for whole site or a specific task list? What is the end target of exporting the schema? You want to create new site/list using same schema?

Comment: i want to export to task list which is enabled to send email to owner. so that, i will fetch the property called email enabled and i can check that property whether it is true or false. If it is true i will export that particular list in csv. This what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below PnP PowerShell command to check if E-Mail Notification is enabled on task list:

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity Tasks -Include EnableAssignToEmail 
$list.EnableAssignToEmail
```

Where `Tasks` is name of list.

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist)

---

**Additional reference**: [Export SharePoint Online List Items To CSV Using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-sharepoint-online-list-items-to-csv-using-pnp-powershell)

Comment: Really thank you @Ganesh Sanp. I have been confusing my self so long for this logic, actually you saved lot of time.... much appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome Liz. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: How to get that list url using pnp powershell

Comment: You can get all lists in the current web using `Get-PnPList` --> Then you can loop on it & add condition for your required list. Check more information at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist

Comment: yes I understood that concept. i can get the list.  But i want to fetch the particular listURL using Pnp powershell. I know getting the list URL in CSOM powershell is easy. But in pnp not able to get it.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/05/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-list-url.html) if it helps.